# help understanding the fql query for mutual friends

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, facebook

Need to get the name and picture of mutual friends without using JS.

Found FQL query below for mutual friends:

`"SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=[targetID] AND uid1 IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=[sourceID])"`

Is there a way that instead of returning just the `uid1` I can get the name and picture of the person?

EDIT
----------- Think I found it.

`"SELECT first_name, last_name, pic_small FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=['targetID'] AND uid1 IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=['sourceID']))
"`

Comment: Is the `friend`-table mirrored? That is, if A is friend with B, is B friend with A? Do you care about duplicates?

Comment: This is coming from facebook, so I believe that YES it is duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT uid, first_name, last_name, pic_small
FROM user
WHERE uid IN (
    SELECT uid2
    FROM friend
    WHERE uid1 = ['sourceID']
)
AND uid IN (
    SELECT uid2
    FROM friend
    WHERE uid1 = ['targetID']
)
```

This will find any user (A), that both the source user (B) and target user (C), are friends with. Not necessarily the other way around; A being friends with B and C.

If the friend-table truly is mirrored, (i.e. for every row (x,y), there is also row (y,x)) this distinction would not matter.

Answer (score 8):

You can get mutual friends with the Graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/mutualfriends/FRIEND_ID
```

You can read more about it in the User object under mutualfriends:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

To further add:

To get the pictures as well:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/mutualfriends/FRIEND_ID/?fields=id,name,picture&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN